# Version Mismatch With React and Remotion

Tags: reactjs, video, remotion, react-video

I am working on a video project, and I am using the Remotion tool to generate the videos.
But I am getting a warning for **Version mismatch** as below.

[image]

I am worried about the dependencies. below are my dependencies, I need your help to remove all the warnings so that I can run my project properly without worrying about dependencies.

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@remotion/cli": "^3.0.0",
        "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "polished": "^4.2.2",
        "qs": "^6.11.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "remotion": "^3.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.11"
    }
```

**Please help me remove all the warnings or what are the correct combination between the above dependencies.**